# Annotations from javax.validation.constraints For Array

Tags: hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, annotations, constraints

I have to do server side validation for the following form class.

```
public class Student
      {
      @NotEmpty
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      @NotEmpty@Email
      private String email;

      //Got stuck here . @NotEmpty is not working with array
      private int[] subjectList;
     }
```

I have to do server side validation for  `subjectList` which an int array(Which will bind from a multi-select dropdown).

How to validate `@NotEmpty` condition for `subjectList`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Student
      {
      @NotEmpty
      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      @NotEmpty@Email
      private String email;

      @NotEmpty@NotNull
      private int[] subjectList;
     }
```

This worked for me.